# Identity in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The new Asp.Net Core 2.1 is really confusing. Specifically the Identity part of it. Everything is missing. Where did these go?

```
AccountController
ManageController
ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
```

How can I customize them if I don't see them?